# How to transform a localTimeString to utcTimeString and back to localTimeString using moment-timezone

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

When someone in my application picks a date and time and I want to store that DateTime in UTC time, how do I transform the stored DateTime back to the user's local timezone?

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone') 
const myTimeZone = 'Europe/Copenhagen'
const nowUTC = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')

const someDanishTime = '2019-04-19 17:00'

const someDanishTimeAsUTC = moment.tz(someDanishTime,myTimeZone)
  .utc()
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') // returns 2019-04-19 15:00

const utcTimeAsSomeDanishTime = moment.tz(someDanishTimeAsUTC, myTimeZone)
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') // returns 2019-04-19 15:00

// I need a way to transform someDanishTimeAsUTC back to someDanishTime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse your input as UTC

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

then you can use [`tz()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) function to convert it to given zone

> The `moment#tz` mutator will change the time zone and update the offset.

Here a live sample:

```js
const myTimeZone = 'Europe/Copenhagen'
const nowUTC = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')

const someDanishTime = '2019-04-19 17:00'

const someDanishTimeAsUTC = moment.tz(someDanishTime, myTimeZone)
  .utc()
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') // returns 2019-04-19 15:00

const utcTimeAsSomeDanishTime = moment.utc(someDanishTimeAsUTC).tz(myTimeZone)
  .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') // returns 2019-04-19 17:00
  
console.log(someDanishTimeAsUTC);
console.log(utcTimeAsSomeDanishTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I needed.